# How to talk about actions with repetition in the past?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, tenses, past-tense

One way to talk about the actions that one commonly did in the past is using the modal "would". Now if I do not want to use it, how I can say my story.

For example,

> When I was a lecturer, I go to the class every Tuesday, first give the new material and then talk about the possible questions of the students. I also upload some new exercises after each session.

In this grammatically correct?

P.S. If I am not wrong one alternative way would be using "used to". I do not want to use it either.

Comment: *I go to* is present tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the present tense to describe habitual actions in the past. If you have an aversion to using 'would' or 'used to', you need to use the simple past tense - "I went to class every Tuesday" and so on.

Comment: This is right, though there is a literary exception: the ‘historic present, used to bring past events vividly before the reader.  So, for example, “I’d just sat down with my beer, where in rushes this man, screaming his head off, followed by an enormous snarling dog..”. I don’t think that this cinematic device can also be used for habitual actions, I am not sure about that.